# Does UNNotificationServiceExtension allow access to user location iif permissions were granted - iOS

Tags: ios, extension-methods, core-location

I have an app which sends user's [push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) based on their locations but I would like to do a second location check on the client just before displaying the push notification (since server-side data can often be outdated or incorrect)

By setting [mutable-content](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications) to 1 in the PUSH payload and implementing [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) I can modify the push before the message is displayed but will the UNNotificationServiceExtension have access to the user's location via [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation) (considering the user has given location access permissions) ?